# What is a good approach to synchronizing JQuery Animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I currently understand $("#someElement").animate() it will execute asynchronously relative to any other JavaScript statements.  For instance:

```
$("#anotherElement").css("display", "none");

$("#someElement").animate(); 

//Setting the CSS display may fire AFTER the animation takes place.
```

If I am correct in my understanding of how animations work, how do I:

1. Make the animations run synchronously with the rest of my code?
2. If I have animations that I'd like to order that affect **different** elements how do I synchronize them to run in a given order?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, you can not run animation synchronously (callbacks only).
2. Use callbacks for this behaviour.

Sample:

```
$('#elem1').animate(params, function () {
    $('#elem2').animate(params, function () {/* ...other elements */});
});
```